# How can a branch be duplicated?

Tags: git, branch

How it should be (in remote):

```
develop

 E  G feature
 D  F 
 | / 
 |/
 |
 C
 B
 A
```

How it is (in remote):

```
develop

 E  G feature
 D  F
 C  C' 
 B  B'
 | / 
 |/
 |
 A
```

So i have several commits on feature and on develop that share the same modifications, name, dates, but not the sha1...

- How is it possible?
- Is there anything to do to prevent it?
- Is there anything to do to correct it?
  `I guess a rebase`

Note:  I'm not the only one to be working in this repo and I don't know what has been done to get to this situation. The root cause of which I would like to understand, in order to prevent it.

Comment: Does your feature branch really have `E` and `D`, or should that be `E'` and `D'`?  The former would be quite surprising.

Comment: sorry no you are true -- post corrected, thanx

Comment: What commits do the branches point to? Which direction is the graph (is higher older or newer)?

Comment: upper is newer, and B and B' as C and C' share the same commit dates

Comment: does develop point to A or E? and does feature point to B' or G?

Comment: If upper is newer, the position of your branch labels in the diagram doesn't make sense (and is confusing). A branch label points at a leaf, not the root. Your diagram in its current form suggests that "A" is the result of merging your "feature" branch into your "development" branch. I've updated your diagrams to match what I think you've described in comments.

Comment: I guess my next question is "why?" since the outcome is functionally the same.

Answer (score 1):

"How is it possible?" Probably someone rebased the remote.
"Can you prevent it?"  Impose a policy that no-one rebases published commits.  "Can you fix it?" You must violate the policy forbidding rebases of published commits.

Most likely, your diagram is slightly misleading, and should in fact show `B'` and `C'` on develop rather than feature.  You forked feature, and then someone else rebased develop and replaced `B` and `C` with `B'` and `C'`.  To fix the issue, you need to rebase the feature branch onto `C'`  (Perhaps I should call that `C''`, the version of `C` currently on the develop branch on the remote.)

Most people recommend not allowing rebases of published commits to prevent this sort of thing from happening.  It would appear that the remote you are referencing does not have that policy, so you can probably rebase your branch and push the changes to the remote.  (There's no technical reason not to do that; the reasons you might not do it are purely policy.  Ask the other developers working on the project.)

Answer (score 1):

> How is it possible?

It looks like one of your branches was rebased at some point. Without knowing more about you got into this situation it's hard to say.

> Is there anything to do to prevent it?

Don't do whatever you did to get into this situation, or just deal
with it after the fact (see next).

> Is there anything to do to correct it? I guess a rebase

Correct. First, make sure your local `develop` branch matches the
remote `develop` branch:

```
git checkout develop
git pull
```

Next, checkout out your `feature` branch and perform an interactive
rebase on `develop`:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase -i develop
```

Delete the erroneous `B'` and `C'` commits.  This will give you:

[image]

At this point, you can force push your `feature` branch to the repository:

```
git push -f origin feature
```

If you actually want your feature branch based on `C` instead of the head of `develop`, you can `git rebase -i <commit id of C on develop>`, but otherwise the process is the same.

As always, work on a copy of your repository if you're worried about mucking something up.

Comment: IMO no need for a copy. Use temporary branches (I put .bak onto old branch names) or use the reflog to revert. Rebasing in git can be "undone"

Comment: Sure, but folks get nervous. Whatever makes you comfortable!